# django admin permission based on model values

Tags: django, django-models, permissions, admin, restriction

my 
models.py:

```
class post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to add a custom permission in the admin for example: 
-can edit only posts of uk 
 
-can see only posts of fr 
-can delete only posts of usa

Comment: need more details,

Comment: for example when i add user  from the admin , i can give him permission to delete only models that belongs to the  country uk, and not oher models

Comment: will you give permission to users ?

Comment: Nobody get an idea with this kind of question, think from reader side, who do you mean by him ?

Comment: yes from the admin . 
by default django is giving me choice to add , update,delete,and view ,but on all instances .
what i want is a custom permission  based on a field which is country  of the model (Post)

Comment: him: means the new user . 
in the django admin: when updating a user . we can give permission to edit or view or delete  certain models .